# Data for most recent date in Power BI for each year

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, window-functions, powerbi-datasource

I have to group on agreement number and get the most recent data for each year. My end goal is to view most recent agreement number for each year so that i don't have repeating agreement number for the year.
I am getting error while using SQL for direct query. How can i get this done in Power BI by other method?

consider a column as agreement number with repeating values and date for 5 years.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4ZH8.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post cellphone photos of your screen of data.  Type in the data into the body of the question.  It only takes a few lines to explain your secnario.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 1):

| Agreement | CreatedOn |
| --- | --- |
| 11600401 | 1/1/2016 |
| 11600402 | 5/5/2016 |
| 11600403 | 8/8/2016 |
| 11600404 | 3/3/2015 |
| 11600405 | 4/4/2015 |
| 11600406 | 2/2/2015 |
| 11600407 | 7/7/2017 |
| 11600408 | 12/12/2017 |
| 11600409 | 5/5/2018 |
| 11600410 | 1/1/2018 |
| 11600408 | 3/3/2018 |

*recent agreement number* is the latest number in each year I assume without checking the date and the measure is a bit simple :

```
Measure = 

MAX ( 'Table'[Agreement] )
```

also add the Year part from [Createdon] to the table

[image: sample result]

[image: columns]

Comment: @Pallavi Please accept as answer if it worked for you...

Answer (score 0):

In power query, you can separate the year from the date field, and group the table by agreement number and year, then return the max result so you can get the most recent date for each year.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).